# assign object keys dynamically using jquery or vanilla js

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an empty object in which I would like to assign data dynamically

**Expected results**

```
userData = {
 programmer: "Jeff",
 designer: "Obama',
 CEO: "Elon Musk"
}
```

What I have tried so far.

```
var userData = {};
var allData = [];

$('input[type="text"]').on("input", function (e) {
    var getBtn = $("#text-label").attr('text-label');
    var inputValue = e.target.value;
    userData.getBtn = inputValue;
    allData.push(userData)
     console.log(allData)
})
```

On console I see

```
[{
    getBtn: "Jim"
}]
```

but the expected result should be

```
[{
        designer: "Jim"
}]
```

What do I need to change to get what I want ?

Comment: `userData.getBtn = inputValue;` to `userData.designer = inputValue;`?

Comment: those  key data are dynamically assigned  as I showed above  if I use as u suggested all of the data will  have the same key

Comment: Please produce a [mcve], including inputs and expected outputs. We can't run the code you've provided, as it's (needlessly) coupled to markup that you haven't shared. Rather than editing your code to include the relevant HTML, your MCVE should just accept inputs and describe the desired  output object, as no part of this actually depends on a working DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

userData[getBtn] = inputValue;